# Ассоциировать данные массива с данными из другого массива

Tags: c#, .net

У меня имеется массив в котором содержатся данные типа

```
компонент масса время ..
метан     0,18  1,21
этан      0,99  2,24
пропан    1,67  4,54
изобутан  4,84  6,36
i-пентан  8,45  7,41
..
```

Мне необходимо чтобы эти данные были записаны в другом порядке. На выходе хочу, чтобы данные из первого массива шли в строго заданном порядке:

```
компонент   
этан 
метан    
i-пентан 
изобутан  
пропан
```

Подскажите пожалуйста максимально простое и изящное решение.
Как ассоциировать первый массив с порядком который мне нужен?

Comment: Отсортировать нужно по какому-либо параметру? [Array.Sort](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=netframework-4.8#System_Array_Sort_System_Array_System_Array_) , где keys - ключи (веса), по которым сортировать, items - ваши данные (названия компонентов).

Comment: Мне нужен строгий порядок как показано в примере

Comment: Если вы точно знаете в каком порядке будут элементы в новом массиве, то просто создайте пустой массив и помещайте в него элементы в нужном порядке. Элегантнее и не придумаешь)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Модель данных:

```
public class Component
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Weight { get; set; }
    public double Time { get; set; }
}
```

Заполняем массив данных и массив ключей. Сортируем.

```
var items = new Component[]
{
    new Component { Name = "метан",    Weight = 0.18, Time = 1.21 },
    new Component { Name = "этан",     Weight = 0.99, Time = 2.24 },
    new Component { Name = "пропан",   Weight = 1.67, Time = 4.54 },
    new Component { Name = "изобутан", Weight = 4.84, Time = 6.36 },
    new Component { Name = "i-пентан", Weight = 8.45, Time = 7.41 },
};

var keys = new int[] { 1, 0, 4, 3, 2 };

Array.Sort(keys, items);
```

Используется перегрузка метода [Array.Sort](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=netframework-4.8#System_Array_Sort_System_Array_System_Array_),
где `keys` - ключи (веса), по которым сортировать, `items` - данные.

Ключи можно задавать в любом виде. Я использовал значения [0..4]. С таким же успехом это могут быть [1..5] или [100..104] или [1001..1005] и т. п.

Answer (score 0):

Класс

```
 public class Component
{
    public string ComponentName;
    public double Wight;
    public double Time;

    //ctor
    public Component(string componentName, double wight, double time )
    {
        ComponentName = componentName;
        Wight = wight;
        Time = time;
    }
}
```

не сортированные данные

```
        List<Component>componentData = new List<Component>();
        Component mentan = new Component("Ментан",0.18,1.21);
        componentData.Add(mentan);
        Component etam = new Component("Этан", 0.99, 2.24);
        componentData.Add(etam);
        Component propan = new Component("Пропан",1.67, 4.54);
        componentData.Add(propan);
        Component izobutan = new Component("Изобутан", 4.84, 6.36);
        componentData.Add(izobutan);
        Component ipetan = new Component("i-Петан", 8.45, 7.41);
        componentData.Add(ipetan);
```

метод для сортировки

```
    public List<Component> SorComponents(List<Component> unsorted)
    {
        List<Component>componentsSorted = new List<Component>();
        int j =0;
        while (true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < unsorted.Count; i++)
            {
                if (unsorted[i].ComponentName == "Ментан" && j==1)
                {
                    componentsSorted.Add(unsorted[i]);
                    j++;
                    break;
                }
                if (unsorted[i].ComponentName == "Этан" && j==0)
                {
                    componentsSorted.Add(unsorted[i]);
                    j++;
                    break;
                }
                if (unsorted[i].ComponentName == "Пропан" && j==4)
                {
                    componentsSorted.Add(unsorted[i]);
                    j++;
                    break;
                }
                if (unsorted[i].ComponentName == "Изобутан" && j==3)
                {
                    componentsSorted.Add(unsorted[i]);
                    j++;
                    break;
                }
                if (unsorted[i].ComponentName == "i-Петан" && j==2)
                {
                    componentsSorted.Add(unsorted[i]);
                    j++;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (j == 5)
            {
                return componentsSorted;
            } 

        }

    }
```

Сортируем

```
var sortedData = SorComponents(componentData);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Чуть позже изучу его.